# Dagger 2 & ViewModel custom scope

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, dagger-2

Currently in my Android MVVM project I have three Dagger scopes:

- Singleton
- Activity scope
- Fragment scope

They are very useful in terms of object lifecycle management. However there is one scenario which I cannot solve:

**Is it technically possible to have a view model scope implemented in Dagger 2?** (view model from arch components of course).

Let's take this scenario for example: I would like to be able to inject the same instance of some class to a view model and a fragment (which is the host for that view model). This instance would have to live as long as the view model lives so if I rotate the screen and fragment gets recreated it would have the same instance injected.

Right now all I can think about is having that instance in Singleton scope, but that's not good since I have to do some manual state management to clear the state of this instance once the view model is destroyed.

Comment: You can have any scope you want in a Dagger setup.  The only predefined one is Singleton.

Comment: You can define a custom scope, but I don't think you can do this with Dagger-Android (which I personally consider to be a major oversight of Dagger-Android). You ***can*** do it with regular Dagger.

Answer (score 0):

You can create annotation class for viewmodels like this

```
@Documented
@MapKey
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ViewModelKey {

    Class<? extends ViewModel> value();
}
```

I have writed it in that repository how to inject viewmodels into the activities https://github.com/ibrahimsn98/android-mvvm-dagger-2-rxjava-example

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible!

Create a custom annotation, annotate the ViewModel and the said class with the custom annotation. In turn, you have to annotate the (sub)component that will provide the ViewModel with this custom annotation as well.

However, the lifetime of the ViewModel will be tied to the (sub)component.